# Assets not loading on symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I try to load css and js files from my symfony project and for all files I have 404.

So, I try like this :

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/css-theme/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

I mention that I create the install of web :

```
php bin/console assets:install web --symlink
```

As result I have :

```
Trying to install assets as absolute symbolic links.
Bundle                  Methode/Error
FrameworkBundle         absolute symlink
[OK] All assets were successfully installed
```

What I'm doing wrong ? Please help me. Thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

You also need to dump assets via command:

```
php bin/console assets:dump
```

This physically writes all of the asset files you need for your environment. The big disadvantage is that you need to run this each time you update an asset

You can use "watch" command so that assets are regenerated automatically as they change.

```
php bin/console assetic:watch
```

More on assets management process here:

[Symfony asset Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/assetic/asset_management.html)

## Edit

Correct command for dump is.

```
php bin/console assetic:dump
```

You may also need to install "assetic" bundle via composer. With a command.

```
composer require symfony/assetic-bundle
```

And add it to your AppKernel:

```
    public function registerBundles()   
    {
        $bundles = array(
            // ...
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
        );
    
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, not "php bin/console assets:dump", but try "php bin/console assetic:dump".

Comment: Which version exactly of symfony are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Since Symfony 2.8 Assetic Bundle is not embebbed with this. You must install first your assetic bundle :

install with composer

```
composer require symfony/assetic-bundle
```

declare bundle in you appKernel

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    // ...

    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            // ...
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
        );

        // ...
    }
}
```

declare config in your config.yml

```
# app/config/config.yml
assetic:
    debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
    use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
```